# Add students name,surname and age from list to ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have 3 `textboxes` where I can enter `Name`,`Surname` and `Age`.
After i press button1, it makes a new student with these attributes.

How can I add student with all 3 attributes to `ListBox`?
Look like this:

> /#/ -- Name -- Surname -- Age
>  1 -- John -- Smith -- 21
>  2 --
>   Tony -- Hawk -- 22

My code at the moment:

```
public class Students
{
     public string Name;
     public string Surname;
     public int Age;
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     List<Students> group = new List<Students>();
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Students student = new Students();
         student.Name = textBox1.Text;
         student.Surname = textBox2.Text;
         student.Age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
         group.Add(student);
     }
}
```

Comment: A listbox seems too simple for what you want (no columns). Perhaps you should better look at other controls like listview or datagridview. If you want to stick to the listbox anyway, you might add the items directly via `yourListBox.Items.Add(row_to_add)`. With the other controls, you might rely on the datasource/databindings and use something like a `List<Student>` variable directly (listbox has also datasource, but it would be problematic here because of the referred simplicity). Hopefully, you will find these ideas helpful, but this question is off-topic (not a code writing service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
listBox1.DataSource = group;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"; //Set the DisplayMember property to avoid call ToString()
```

Or this:

```
foreach (var item in group)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Also you shoud change the fields in your class to properties like this:

```
public class Students
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} -- {1} -- {2}", Name, Surname, Age);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I think you want this (By pressing button it adds to the `ListBox` and you don't need the `group` list anymore. Just don't forget to override the `ToString` in the class):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Students student = new Students();
    student.Name = textBox4.Text;
    student.Surname = textBox5.Text;
    student.Age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(student);         
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's working now :) Can u abit explain that override ToString() ? Why is it needed?

Comment: @RobertsŠensters... Read more about overriding the `ToString` in details here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If applicable, you should also have an ID (unless your specification says otherwise.) to contain the 1, 2, etc. For actually displaying the information, you can override the ToString() method to display it in the list box how you want.

```
public class Student
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Surname { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
     public int ID { get; set; }

     public override string ToString()
     {
          return string.Format("{0} -- {1} -- {2} -- {3}", ID, Name, Surname, Age);
     }
}
```

and setting the DataSource on your ListBox to 'group'.

Comment: Don't forget string interpolation with the formatted string. `return $"{ID} -- {Name} -- {Surname} -- {Age}"` :)

Comment: After i get 1st student in the listbox, it doesn't show any other students.

Comment: @DanielHakimi true, assuming he's using VS2015 or installed roslyn :).